# multiple line reading from txt file C++

Tags: c++, loops

From file txt.

```
44 55 77 88
79 88 100 99
77 99 98 99
100 88 89 100
55 56 40 77
```

how do i read line by line to add and get the average? This is what I have so far.

```
int main()
{

    ifstream numberInputFile;
    int sum = 0.0, average = 0.0;
    int test1, test2, test3, test4;    
    numberInputFile.open("grades.txt");
    if (numberInputFile)
    {
        while (numberInputFile >> test1 >> test2 >> test3 >> test4)
        {
            sum += (test1 + test2 + test3 + test4);

            //find the average

            average = sum / 4;

            if(average >= 90 && average <= 100)
            {
                cout << average << " A" <<endl;
            }
            else if(average >= 80 && average < 90)
            {
                cout << average << " B" <<endl;
            }
            else if(average >= 70 && average < 80)
            {
                cout << average << " C" <<endl;
            }
            else if(average >= 60 && average < 70)
            {
                cout << average << " D" <<endl;
            }
            else if(average < 60)
            {
                cout << average << " F" <<endl;
            }
            else
                numberInputFile.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hows does what you have not do what you want?

Comment: Have you tested it? What are the issues?

Comment: It's only reading the first line and stops.

Comment: If you want to have the average per file line, you should calculate ` sum = test1 + test2 + test3 + test4;` instead of `sum += test1 + test2 + test3 + test4;`

Comment: "only reading the first line" Sure - you close the file within your while loop... Problem is my comment above: `sum +=`: in the second loop run, sum gets 630, which is, devided by 4, > 100, so you run into your else... Afterwards, operator>> fails and you leave your loop.

Comment: Looks like that did the job. Was sum += only reading the first number and then breaking the loop?

Comment: @Dip Not exactly. You read in four numbers in the first loop run, summing them up. sum was initialised to 0, so fine. In the second loop run, you again read four(!) numbers and sum them up. But as you had sum +=, you added the second line's result to the first one, resulting in the total sum of all eight values read so far (630). Now you get into your else, closing the file. The next call to `operator>>` (within your while condition) then fails -- and *this* is what breaks your loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
if (numberInputFile)
    {}
        while (numberInputFile >> test1 >> test2 >> test3 >> test4)
        {}
```

Try :

```
 string line;
    while(getline(inFile, line))
    { 
     std::istringstream iss(line)
      while(iss >> test)
        {  sum+=test;
            .
            .
            ..
        }
    //Check average here, outside the loop

    }
```